# Bug in Data.Map implementation?

Tags: haskell, containers, monadfix, tying-the-knot

I've stumbled upon something that I'm *guessing* is a bug in `Data.Map`, but which is also quite possibly a bug in my Haskell knowledge. Hoping somebody can clarify which it is :)

Please reference [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2984512). I'm serializing a circular linked list structure to a bytestream. For any given node, of the form:

```
data Node = Node
  { val  :: Word8
  , next :: Node
  }
```

I expect it to be serialized as a pair of bytes: the first byte representing `val`, and the second byte representing the offset in the bytestream where `next` can be located. For example, I expect:

```
let n0 = Node 0 n1
    n1 = Node 1 n0
```

to be serialized as `[0, 1, 1, 0]`. No big deal.

The slightly tricky part here is that I'm exploiting the `MonadFix` instance for `RWST` to "tie the knot" of bytestream offsets: I maintain a map from nodes to offsets, populating the map during serialization, but also referencing entries in the map that don't necessarily exist yet until serialization is complete.

This works great when the map implementation is [`Data.HashMap.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/latest/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html) (from [unordered-containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.1.0)).  However, when the implementation is the usual [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html) (from [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0)), the program stack overflows -- no pun intended -- with `Map` trying infinitely to compare the two nodes using `(==)`.

**So my question is:** is this a bug in `Data.Map`, or are my assumptions about how these structures should behave in the presence of `mfix` flawed?

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka this takes the place of my previous horrible post, which I've deleted. You asked to see the code in full, so here you go :)

Comment: Also, I just discovered (to my surprise) that `Data.HashMap.Strict` also works fine.

Comment: and now you see exactly why I asked to see the code ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your `Ord` instance doesn't work:

```
instance Ord Node where -- for use in Data.Map
  Node a _ < Node b _ = a < b
```

For a working `Ord` instance, you must define `compare` or `(<=)`. If you only define `(<)`, any call to `compare` or `(<=)` will loop infinitely since both have default implementations in terms of each other. Also the other members of `Ord` are defined in terms of `compare`, so nothing except `(<)` will work.

Comment: **Damn it, I'm an idiot.** I just realized that myself. Good thing I have no problem making an ass of myself on the internet.

Comment: @mergeconflict There is no shame in that!  If you are not embarrassing yourself you are not learning!

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Amen to that. I teach for a living, and I often tell my students the same thing :)

Comment: @mergeconflict it's so hard to apply the word one teaches to oneself - I teach too.